# I need to add English sources, and Arabic numbers with the correct order

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, citing, languages, arabic

This is how the references look like, I have a problem that the numbers are in the wrong direction (like the years are 2991 instead of 1992, and when I add English sources like the one first one it looks in the wrong order, this is the code I am using since I have an Arabic report:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\fontfamily{Simplified Arabic}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {figures/} }
\usepackage[arabic]{babel}
\begin{document}
........
\end{document}
```

And this is the bibliography code:

```latex
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
...........
\end{thebibliography}
```

[image: PDF preview on Overleaf]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please post a [minimum working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that generates the problem behavior you wish to fix.